# I cant insert date from codeigniter into mysql DATE column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**CONTROLLER**

```
$date=date("Y-d-m");
$succes=$this->pl->insert_ad($brandID,$model,$price,$year,$picture,$resized,$fuels,$id_usera,$date);
```

**Model**

```
public function insert_ad($brand,$model,$price,$year,$picture,$resized,$fuels,$date)
{
 $sql1="INSERT INTO `ads`(`model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `date`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`)
         VALUES ('".$model."','".$year."','".$price."','".$picture."','".$date."','".$resized."','".$fuels."','".$brand."')";
  $this->db->query($sql1);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

I print it with `print_r($date)` and it displays `2016-03-16`, I really dont now why it wont insert like everything else.

Table structure 
[image]

Comment: share table schema also ?

Comment: use `$date=date("Y-m-d");`

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` and see what query is building

Answer (score 1):

```
I just tried this minutes ago and it worked! ^_^

$d = date("Y-m-d");
$t = date("h:i:s");

$this->db->set($this->col_prefix.'customer_id', $_POST['customer_id']); 
$this->db->set($this->col_prefix.'total_amount', $_POST['total_amount']); 
$this->db->set('date', "'".$d."'"); 
$this->db->set('time_in', "'".$t."'"); 
$this->db->set('status', 1); 
$this->db->insert('sln_transactions');

but haven't tried it yet in array :) hope this could help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check data-type of 'date' column in database table. Might be possible issue.

Try these functions :

> date('Y/m/d');
>   date('h-m-s');
>   date('Y/m/d:h-m-s');

I used these in particular to get the date and time. Might help you as well.

Comment: for date alone: date('Y/m/d'); and for time: date('h-m-s'); for both date and time date('Y/m/d:h-m-s');

Answer (score 0):

Change From

```
$date=date("Y-d-m");
```

To

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
```

And remvoe `'` from integer type

```
public function insert_ad($brand,$model,$price,$year,$picture,$resized,$fuels,$date)
{
 $sql1="INSERT INTO `ads` (`id_ad`, `model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `date`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`) VALUES (NULL, '$model', '$year', '$price', '$picture', '".date('Y-m-d')."', '$resized', '$fuels', '$brand')";
  $this->db->query($sql1);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: @VBProgramming can you share table schema ?

Comment: @VBProgramming and also value of  _echo $sql1_ ?

Comment: [link](http://s12.postimg.org/ru3n4hr7h/database_schema.png)
and $sql1 returns true

Comment: updated ans,try now  ? and I was asking your complete sql query ?

Comment: Not true/false complete query string sir? _echo $sql1="INSERT INTO `ads`(`model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `date`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`)
         VALUES ('".$model."','".$year."',".$price.",'".$picture."','".$date."','".$resized."',".$fuels.",".$brand.")";_

Comment: 'INSERT INTO `ads`(`model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `date`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`) VALUES ('A8',2008,2323,'/images/1467211_729048773816961_5472893197061538773_n66.jpg','1970-01-01','/images/resized_1467211_729048773816961_5472893197061538773_n66.jpg',2,2)'

Comment: And without this '$date =  gmdate('Y-d-m', strtotime($date));' 
It displays 1124
But,from controller it displays normally 2016-03-16

Comment: your year value should come in single quote ('2008') as in my ans. also your date seems wrong, after change can run your query in your phpmyadmin ?

Comment: I updated once again my ans, hope it will work for you, what error you are getting in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: I tried in phpmyadmin after changing it,and it works only in phpmy admin when i manually type values
Query that i ran in phpmyadmin `INSERT INTO `ads`(`model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `date`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`) VALUES ('Alfa-Romeo',2008,10000,'/images/1467211_729048773816961_547289319706153877.jpg','2008-5-10','/images/1467211_729048773816961_547289319706153877.jpg',1, 1)`

Comment: **Thank you SO much** i really appreciate your help it finally works .This is my fist day on stack ,how can i rate you or something ?

Comment: I dont now how to give you 5 stars,or i cant because I am new

Answer (score 0):

Change your `insert_ad` function as below:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO `ads`(`model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`,`resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`,`date`) VALUES ('".$model."','".$year."','".$price."','".$picture."','".$resized."','".$fuels."','".$brand."',NOW())";
$this->db->query($sql1);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

Also remove the date parameter in controller function call and model function definition.

Comment: Finally something ,with this code add it inserts this 1970-01-01

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER**

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
```

Database date format is `Y-m-d` not `Y-d-m`

Comment: Actually no ,sorry

Answer (score 0):

Make your query like this. Use `DATE(".$date.")`

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO `ads`(`model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `date`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`)
         VALUES ('".$model."','".$year."','".$price."','".$picture."',DATE(".$date."),'".$resized."','".$fuels."','".$brand."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

**Controller:**

```
    $date=date("Y-d-m");
    $succes=$this->pl->insert_ad(array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'id_brand'=>$brandID,
        'price'=>$price,
        'photo'=>$picture,
        'date'=>$date,
        'resized_photo'=>$resized,
        'id_fuel'=>$id_usera,
        'year'=>$year));
```

**Model:**

```
public function insert_ad($data) {
    $this->db->insert('ads', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: Could you try to change the column 'date' to anything else, as 'date' is system keyword, it's not suggested to be used as column name.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER **
*The correct formats of date * `$date=date("Y-m-d");` *and * `$date = date("Y-d-m");` *as well*

```
 public function insert_ad($brand,$model,$price,$year,$picture,$resized,$fuels,$date)
 {
     $sql1="INSERT INTO `ads` (`id_ad`, `model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `date`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`) VALUES (NULL, '$model', '$year', '$price', '$picture', '".date('Y-m-d')."', '$resized', '$fuels', '$brand')";
     $this->db->query($sql1);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using type varchar in your database structure for date.

Answer (score 0):

this work perfect for me

in controller function

```
$this->model_invoice->invoice_create();
```

in model

```
  $invoice_date = strtotime($this->input->post('invoice_date_time'));
     $date=date("Y-m-d", $invoice_date);

    $data = array
   (
    'invoice_date_time' =>  $date,
    );

    $this->db->insert('your_table_name', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in your Controller delete your variable $data
 and also in your model delete the variable

model

```
    public function insert_ad($brand,$model,$price,$year,$picture,$resized,$fuels)
{
 $sql1="INSERT INTO `ads`(`model`, `year`, `price`, `photo`, `resized_photo`, `id_fuel`, `id_brand`)
         VALUES ('".$model."','".$year."','".$price."','".$picture."','".$date."','".$resized."','".$fuels."','".$brand."')";
  $this->db->query($sql1);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

and also in your db change 
**type** as **DATETIME** and 
**PREDETERMINATED** as **CURRENT_TIME**
and run it

hope this works!